# Only a part of the button clickable

Tags: html, css, image, click, clickable

I made two buttons, but only a part of the buttons is clickable, the whole part of the button should be clickable. I used position absolute to give the buttons a place in my page.

**The hml code:**

```
<div class="knop">
<a href="https://mylink"><div class="sideLeft"><image 
src="images/knop.png"></div></a>
</div>
<div class="knop">
<a href="https://mylink"><div class="sideRight"><image 
src="images/knop1.png"></div></a>
</div>
```

**With this css:**

```
.sideLeft{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
position: absolute;
Top: 41%;
display: block;
}
.sideRight{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
position: absolute;
Top: 41%;
right: 0px; 
display: block
}
.knop img{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
}
```

**Image:**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4uB3.png)

Comment: isn't that <img> tag instead of <image> ?

Comment: From the code you provided, I could not duplicate your issue. I suspect a conflict with other CSS styling that you haven't provided. Perhaps there's even an (invisible) element that's layered over the buttons, blocking the mouse click event.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure your button is on the top of other elements add this to it's class:

```
z-index: 999;
```

> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An
>   element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with
>   a lower stack order.

This `(999)` number can be anywhere from `0` to `2147483647` in most browsers.

[More about z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

You should use `<img` instead of `<image`.